# Checking ScrollBar of TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a simple asp:textbox set up like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxWarning" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4">
</asp:TextBox>
```

The SUBMIT button on the page does not become active until you scroll to the bottom of the textbox.  This part works except that sometimes the textbox does not have enough data in it to make the textbox scrollable.  How can I check (with either javascript or jQuery) wether or not the scrollbar in the textbox is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript `.clientHeight` property of a textarea (or any other element) tells you how many pixels can be seen. The  `.scrollHeight` property tells how how many pixels can be scrolled. If they are equal, there's no scrollbar.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MeCKR/1/ -- you can also force scrolling to the bottom by setting `.scrollTop`.